# How can I keep video player responsive when resizing height in full screen

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design, html5-video

I have a video player in full screen inside page and it's responsive only if I drag the corner or left and right edge of the browser, not if I try to resize using the bottom edge of the browser going up. If I try resizing going up it just cuts off the video since i have the overflow hidden, or it shows the scrollbar if I don't have overflow hidden. I was hoping I could show black spacing but keeping the bottom of the player visible so I can see the toolbar in the player. What's the best way to keep responsive no matter how I resize the browser?

```
<div class="video-player-page">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <!-- video player here -->
            <div id="video-player"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should do it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var video_w = $('#video_w');
        var videoRatio = 1.77;
        var windowRatio = 1.6; //this is width to height ratio of video.
        $(window).resize(function () {
            setVideoHeight();
        });
        function setVideoHeight() {
            windowRatio = $(window).width() / $(window).height();
            video_w.addClass('resized');
            if (windowRatio < videoRatio) {
                video_w.width($(window).width());
                video_w.height(video_w.width() / videoRatio);
            }
            else {

                video_w.height($(window).height());
                video_w.width(video_w.height().videoRatio);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
<style>
    #video_w video {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #video_w.resized video {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
    }

    .row_video {
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
```

html markup

```
<div id="video_w">
            <video controls="controls">
                <source src="big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. Works!